# Comparing Overlap in Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I have four columns in a pandas dataframe, column A, B, C and D. Column A contains 30 words, 18 of which are in column B. Column C contains either a 1 or 2 (keyboard response to column B words) and column D contains 1 or 2 also (the correct response).

What I need to do is see the total correct for only the words where column A and B overlap. I understand how to compare the C and D columns to get the total correct once I have the correct dataframe, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around comparing the overlap in A and B.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected outputs to this question.

Comment: You can try `df.isin`. It's fast and will give you the boolean values and if you want the count either use `astype(int) ` or `set` depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.B.isin(df.A)
```

That will give you a boolean Series the same length as `df.B` indicating for each value in `df.B` whether it is also present in `df.A`.